# Replace date in a DateTime with another date

Tags: c#

How do you change the day part of a `DateTime` structure?

I have a `DateTime` with the value of 3/31/2009 8:00:00 AM and would like to change it to any other date but the time should be same. I don't need a solution to add day(s), I need to replace it with any arbitrary date.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
day = 1
month = 4
year = 2009

Date2 = new DateTime(day,month,year,Date1.Hours,Date1.Minute,Date1.Seconds)
```

Answer (score 13):

To construct a DateTime from two other DateTimes, one of which contains the date and one of which contains the time, you can use:

```
DateTime result = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 5):

s = s.AddDays(1)

Comment: Not to add 1 day to given date.But to replace datepart in datetime with another date.Can u help to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime.AddDays method. Like this:

```
DateTime s2 = s.AddDays( 1 );
```